# Does a favored soul have alignment restriction on their spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, alignment

As title says. It doesn't say anywhere in the class description that they have alignment restriction like clerics but it seems weird to me that a favored soul of a good deity can cast evil spells. They even have to follow the alignment rule that they need to be a step close to their deity

The only clue i could find is that it says that favored souls get spells from the cleric spell list, but that's all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RAW:** A Favored Soul of a good deity can cast any spell from the cleric list he/she wants. There are no restrictions.

**IMO:** The Complete _ books aren't all that well written and it seems odd that a paragon of a good deity would sully themselves by casting such spells. As a DM I would probably not allow it or sit down with the player and discuss shifting alignment/deities to match how they want their character to act.

**In summary:** There's nothing to stop a FS casting spells against their deity's alignment. It's a bit against the spirit of the class though.

Comment: Just as i thought (feared), thanks. Looks like someone will have to face their gods wrath though

Comment: Please do not use the term RAI unless you are prepared to demonstrate that this was actually the intent of the authors at the time, usually through quoting developer commentary. Otherwise it is just your opinion, not theirs. I completely agree with your opinion here but you should label it accurately for readers and you should not put words in the authors’ mouths.

Comment: Good point well taken

Comment: @KRyan - sounds like good advice, but the most ubiquitous use of the RAI term on rgp.se is speculation from context.

Comment: @Wyrmwood No, that is the most common use of the term *outside* RPG SE. That usage has been rejected on meta as a poor choice, and is *not* recommended here—personally, I downvote any case of it. Answers are required to be backed up—asserting that something was the author’s intent without backing it up makes for a bad answer, ever single time. If you see any misuse of the term, personally I think you should do as I did, downvote and leave a comment explaining.

Comment: Just do a search and then look at some of the results. I couldn't find ANY that actually quoted a source.